# android: Bitmap decodeFile returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I am unit testing some images from a resources folder. I am mocking the BitmapFactory method with [Power Mock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock)

```
   PowerMockito.mockStatic(BitmapFactory::class.java)

      val bitmap: Bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
```

Everything works fine just that I get an error trying to decode the image path. I am very certain that the path string is not null. The image path is something like this:

```
/$project location/android/app/build/intermediates/java_res/devDebugUnitTest/out/images/image.jpg
```

What could be the reason for this error:

```
decodeFile(images[0].fullPath) must not be null

java.lang.NullPointerException: decodeFile(imagePath) must not be null
    at biometrics.utils.BiometricFunctionsHelper$Companion.processImages(BiometricFunctionsHelper.kt:71)
    at BiometricsTests.before(BiometricsTests.kt:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:133)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
```

There is no much details about this error which makes it hard to fix. I tried reducing the size of the image but still didnt work. Please help

Comment: What do you expect to decodeFile to return?

Comment: A bitmap from the image

Comment: Yes it returns a valid bitmap. Or null. It will never return a NullPointerException as you suggest in the subject of your post.

Comment: I dont understand your comment. I showed the stacktrace with showed that I get a null pointer while trying to decode a file path into a Bitmap

Comment: Why is the method returning null even when the image is valid?